# Progress bar android aac player issue

Tags: android

Hi im trying to get a progress bar from my aacplayer in android i have already this code:

```
public void playerPCMFeedBuffer(boolean isPlaying, final int bufSizeMs, final int bufCapacityMs) {
    float percent = bufSizeMs * 100 / bufCapacityMs;
    System.out.println("Buffer = " + percent + "% , "+bufSizeMs+" / "+bufCapacityMs);

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            progress.setProgress(bufSizeMs * 100 / bufCapacityMs);

        }
    });
```

this give me the buffer of the audio stream so i think i can set progress bar from that and show the progress bar moving itself. But im getting this error:

```
03-11 00:15:15.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7609): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 00:15:15.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7609): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 00:15:15.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7609):     at com.webcraftbd.radio.RadioService$1$1.run(RadioService.java:712)
03-11 00:15:15.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7609):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-11 00:15:15.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7609):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-11 00:15:15.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7609):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-11 00:15:15.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7609):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-11 00:15:15.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7609):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 00:15:15.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7609):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 00:15:15.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7609):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-11 00:15:15.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7609):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-11 00:15:15.885: E/AndroidRuntime(7609):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thank you very much.

Comment: at com.webcraftbd.radio.RadioService$1$1.run(RadioService.java:712)
That's your class ?
Because thats where your problem seems to be..
It's an NPE, debug through your code and find the exact place where the error occurs. You probably forgot to initialize some variable.

Comment: where have you initialized `progress` ? from the code you posted it seems like it would be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.out.println() isn't valid in android development.  Use

```
  Log.d("tag", "message");
```

instead

Comment: It seems reasonable to assume that the error you posted was caused by the System.out.println() though doesn't it, bro?

Comment: no bro, as that print or log is just informative that works perfect if i remove it im still getting the issue stated before (progressbar) so the issue is not the log thing.